# arduino and esp8266 problem

Tags: linux-mint, usb, arduino

I can't seem to connect my esp8266 d1 mini; can any one help me?

This is the error msg I get:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Linux), Board: "LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 mini (clone), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, DOUT (compatible), 40MHz, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 921600"

Executable segment sizes:
ICACHE : 32768           - flash instruction cache 
IROM   : 231788          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 
IRAM   : 26777   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (IRAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 
DATA   : 1496  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
RODATA : 876   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
BSS    : 25616 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
Sketch uses 260937 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 27988 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53932 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oem/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py", line 322, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oem/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/upload.py", line 66, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "/home/oem/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 3551, in main
    esp = chip_class(each_port, initial_baud, args.trace)
  File "/home/oem/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/esptool/esptool.py", line 271, in __init__
    self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
  File "/home/oem/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/pyserial/serial/__init__.py", line 90, in serial_for_url
    instance.open()
  File "/home/oem/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.0/tools/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py", line 325, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
the selected serial port serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: You will get better readability if you read the formatting tips at unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help Enclosing multi-line quotes between lines with triple back-quotes is especially good. I've done this, on this occasion.